# Parsing prices from HTML returns blank or no value?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm not seeing any success in this, as no matter what I do it returns blank values only.

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.oficinadosbits.com.br/produto18064/EVGA_GeForce_GTX_980_04G-P4-2983-KR.html"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))

price = page.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/font[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span").text

puts price
```

I tried using CSS and also Mechanize, but without success:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new

page = mechanize.get("http://www.oficinadosbits.com.br/produto18064/EVGA_GeForce_GTX_980_04G-P4-2983-KR.html")

doc = page.parser

price = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/font[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span").text

puts price
```

When I use:

```
puts price.size
```

at the end it returns a zero. How come it reads zero values?

I'd like to understand why this is happening, and how I could solve it in order to be able to parse the prices.

I got the xpath from Firebug's "copy xpath" option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't care your experience, we just want well thought-out questions showing effort. "[ask]" explains it all. Don't use browser-based tools to get the HTML or to determine a selector. The browser messes with the HTML so what it shows is usually not trustworthy. Also, using "copy xpath" results in a long and fragile selector. Instead, use `wget` or `curl` or Nokogiri itself to retrieve the page and look at it there, outside of the browser. Then figure out way-points in the document used to navigate to your desired node(s).

Comment: Also, when asking about your code, we need the minimal input data and your expected output *in the question itself*. Please read "[mcve]". It helps us help you, and it helps those in the future trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's tons of helpful css on that page:

```
page.at('[itemprop=price]').text
#=> "R$ 3.459,90"
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! This one really helped me. Would you mind explaining to me why the brackets instead of parenthesis in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, attributes always go in brackets. If you're not familiar with that, read some css documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `tbody` in `/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[1]`. But you could have checked that yourself.

```
page.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[1]")
# => lots of output
page.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody")
# => whoopsie.
```

The issue is, FireBug's "Copy XPath" will give you the XPath for the DOM as it is in the browser at the moment when you requested it, which can differ from the DOM of the source document for various reasons: e.g. DOM changed by JavaScript, or certain nodes automatically inserted by the browser.

Comment: I totally trusted FireBug's "Copy XPath" blindly. As I said, I'm a beginner, and was thinking the problem could be something else. Thanks a lot for these tips!

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri supports both XPath and CSS selectors. I generally go with CSS for readability and simplicity, but XPath is important to know also as it has a lot of power.

Consider this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="p1" class="paragraphs" foo="bar">some text</p>
    <p id="p2" class="paragraphs" foo="baz">some text</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT
```

We can find nodes by their tag:

```
p_nodes = doc.search('p')
p_nodes.class             # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
p_nodes.size              # => 2
p_nodes.map(&:to_html)    # => ["<p id=\"p1\" class=\"paragraphs\" foo=\"bar\">some text</p>", "<p id=\"p2\" class=\"paragraphs\" foo=\"baz\">some text</p>"]
```

Using `search` returns a NodeSet, which is akin to an Array. In this example it found two `<p>` tags.

Compare that to using `at`:

```
p_node = doc.at('p') 
p_node.class                            # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
p_node = doc.at('p#p2').to_html         # => "<p id=\"p2\" class=\"paragraphs\" foo=\"baz\">some text</p>"
p_node = doc.at('p.paragraphs').to_html # => "<p id=\"p1\" class=\"paragraphs\" foo=\"bar\">some text</p>"
```

`at` is the equivalent to taking the first element found by `search`, but it returns an Element/Node. A node could contain more nodes/tags, and a NodeSet would be an array of nodes, and in all cases, a node is like a pointer into the document which is useful to navigating around.

```
doc.at('body').at('p') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd431448c6c name="p" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448c08 name="id" value="p1">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448bf4 name="class" value="paragraphs">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448be0 name="foo" value="bar">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd431448384 "some text">]>
doc.at('body > p')     # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd431448c6c name="p" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448c08 name="id" value="p1">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448bf4 name="class" value="paragraphs">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448be0 name="foo" value="bar">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd431448384 "some text">]>
doc.at('p')            # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd431448c6c name="p" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448c08 name="id" value="p1">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448bf4 name="class" value="paragraphs">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd431448be0 name="foo" value="bar">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd431448384 "some text">]>
```

Notice how the address of the node

```
Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd431448c6c
```

remains the same in the above results.

Building on top of that, to find nodes in the HTML we can navigate using various parameters:

```
doc.at('p[foo="baz"]').to_html # => "<p id=\"p2\" class=\"paragraphs\" foo=\"baz\">some text</p>"

doc.search('p[foo="baz"]').size # => 1
doc.search('p[foo="baz"]').first.to_html # => "<p id=\"p2\" class=\"paragraphs\" foo=\"baz\">some text</p>"
```

The take-away of this is, we should inspect the HTML, find specific nodes that get us to the information we want, then write the minimum selector to get there. Long selectors are more likely to break if the HTML changes.

Finally, beware of using browsers to inspect the code as they mess with tables. I created a file containing:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Opening it in Firefox, Opera or Safari and inspecting the page resulted in HTML that had been modified:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Don't trust the browser and instead use `wget`, `curl` or Nokogiri's own command-line:

```
$ nokogiri http://example.com
Your document is stored in @doc...
irb(main):001:0> @doc
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x3fd748d60740 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x3fd748d41a5c name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d41750 name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d41534 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d41430 name="head" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d41200 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d41138 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d40f44 "Example Domain">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d40d78 "\n\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d40cb0 name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d40c4c name="charset" value="utf-8">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d40544 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d40454 name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d403dc name="http-equiv" value="Content-type">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d403c8 name="content" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d3d934 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d3d858 name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d3d7a4 name="name" value="viewport">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d3d77c name="content" value="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d3ce1c "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d3cd68 name="style" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d3cd04 name="type" value="text/css">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x3fd748d3c4bc "\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 50px;\n        background-color: #fff;\n        border-radius: 1em;\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        body {\n            background-color: #fff;\n        }\n        div {\n            width: auto;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            border-radius: 0;\n            padding: 1em;\n        }\n    }\n    ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d3c0e8 "    \n">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d39e38 "\n\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d39d48 name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d39adc "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d39a00 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d397bc "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d39460 name="h1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d39118 "Example Domain">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d38f60 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d38e84 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d38c7c "This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d38ab0 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d389fc name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd748d38808 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd748d387a4 name="href" value="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d38344 "More information...">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d38088 "\n">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d35eb4 "\n">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd748d35cfc "\n">]>]>
irb(main):002:0> @doc.at('a').to_html
=> "<a href=\"http://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a>"
irb(main):003:0> @doc.at('a')['href']
=> "http://www.iana.org/domains/example"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the price of:

```
"GeForce GTX 980 4GB GDDR5 256bits - Game Grátis - EVGA 04G-P4-2983-KR"
```

you can use Nokogiri with a CSS selector:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.oficinadosbits.com.br/produto18064/EVGA_GeForce_GTX_980_04G-P4-2983-KR.html"))
price = doc.css("html > body > div")[0].css("div > div > table[1] > tr")[0].css("td[3] > table")[1].css("tr > td")[1].css("span")[0].text
```

Comment: Oh. My. `css(...)[0]` is the same as `at(...)` so take advantage of `at` and its variants. Your method of selecting a node is very fragile as a change in the page will break it. Instead, find way-points and use those to locate your desired node. See @pguardiario's answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation! I saw that @pguardiario's solution is so clean. Is it safe against minor changes on the html?